# I only want my audio mp3 file to play one time and it's not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an audio that the user can start and stop. That works fine but I only want the audio to play through one time. Currently it keeps looping and I definitely don't want that. Can someone tell me how I can make this play through one time then stop? Thank you.

**HTML5**

```
<div class="container">
            <h3>A word on meditation</h3>
            <button id="play">Play</button> &nbsp;<button id="pause">Stop</button>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/thoseWhoMeditate.mp3');

    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);

    $('#play').click(function() {
        audioElement.play();
    });

    $('#pause').click(function() {
        audioElement.pause();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about jquery instructions, but maybe change the event type to load:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/thoseWhoMeditate.mp3');

audioElement.addEventListener('load', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);

$('#play').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
});

$('#pause').click(function() {
    audioElement.pause();
});
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks very much.